# MonoTouch UIViewController initWithNibName

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to load a view controller contained within a referenced library as well as a separate asset bundle.  In order to do this, I believe I need to use the method initWithNibName.  I have added the following additional mtouch arguments:

```
-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-L${TargetDir} -F${TargetDir} -F${ProjectDir} -F${TargetDir}/Test.embeddedframework -framework Test"
```

This Objective-C snippet does exactly what I need to do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.embeddedframework",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
NSString *nib = [myBundle pathForResource:@"TestViewController" ofType:@"nib"];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:myBundle];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

From within MonoTouch, I've been able to load compile bindings and load the asset bundle.  But I'm unaware of how to send the message 'initWithNibName'.  The API docs are not complete for this method, but show a constructor on UIViewController that will accept a nib name and bundle.  However, this does not appear to be included in the generated DLL.

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=C%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController(System.String%2cMonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle)

Does anyone have any experience with doing something like this or have any suggestions as to how it can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about a selector one of the best way to find the MonoTouch match is to use Miguel's [Rosetta Stone](http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html). That will tell you to which method (or constructor) a specific selector was binded too.

If you want to inherit form the an existing type (e.g. using `btouch`) then you should write some additional code (in a separate .cs file) to be compiled inside the generated .dll (a bit like additional `enums` you like to add to a binded API). This is possible since the generator will be producing (source-wise) partial classes.

Comment: Thanks for link, I had not encountered that before.  However, this doesn't seem to help me much. I see the constructor is defined, same as is in the API docs - but I still have not seen this within the generated dll.  I did create bindings for the class, but since the message 'initWithNibName' is on UIViewController directly, I did not define my own binding.  Is this a mistake?

Basically my api.cs class is almost empty since I'm doing nothing more than extending UIViewController at this time.  I have defined an interface for the controller, but no additional instance methods.  Make runs fine.

Comment: I took advice and specifically added constructor in binding like: [Export("initWithNibName:bundle:")]
IntPtr Constructor (string nibName, NSBundle bundle);  but when I attempt to use it I get: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <..../TestHarness.app/Test.embeddedframework> (not yet loaded)' with name 'TestViewController.nib'   I've been at this error in the past and do not have a resoluttion - any further suggestions?  Thanks again